# Open Excel from VBA in Word

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I use Office for Mac and I want to open Excel (and then a document within it) using a macro in Word.

```
Dim myexl As Excel.Application '(1)
Dim myworkbook As Workbooks
Dim my_path As String
```

...

```
Set myexl = CreateObject("Excel.Application") '(2)
Set myworkbook = myexl.Workbooks.Open(my_path) '(3)
```

However, the line (2) generates "Type mismatch" in the above code. If I try to switch (1) so that instead it reads

```
Dim myexl As Object
```

then (2) works but now I get "Object doesn't support this property or method" for line (3)! This is like a catch 22.

How can I solve this? I want to open Excel and still be able to use the methods of an Excel.Application. Is there some way to cast the type or something similar?

Comment: `Dim myworkbook As Workbook` <--- singular (the plural is a collection of workbooks)

Comment: And `Dim myexl As Object` is the correct way when using Late Binding with `CreateObject("Excel.Application")`.

Comment: I made a typo and it it should be `Dim myworkbook As Workbook` indeed.

@PEH, but if I do this, then I cannot use `myexl.Workbooks.Open(my_path)`! What should I do in this case then?

Can I use Early Binding somehow?

Comment: @JezuzStardust Because there is no reference to Excel in `Late Binding` the class `As Workbook` does not exist in Word. Therefore you need either to use `Early Binding` and reference Excel, or declare `Dim myworkbook As Object` too. See HTH's answer below.

Answer (score 3):

use `Object` type for `myworkbook` variable,  too:

```
    Dim my_path As String
    my_path = "some valid path to wanted workbook"

    On Error GoTo SafeExit
    Dim myexl As Object
    Set myexl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

    Dim myworkbook As Object
    Set myworkbook = myexl.Workbooks.Open(my_path)

    myexl.Visible = True


    ...

SafeExit:
    MsgBox Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description
    If Not myexl Is Nothing Then myexl.Quit ' <-- this will close the excel instance you opened (if any)
    Set myexl = Nothing
```

Comment: Your analysis is important. And so is my question for me

Comment: As was written in my question, this does not work unfortunately. Just as @slightlysnarky said, declaring myexl as Object prevents me from then using `myexl.Workbooks.Open`. This feels very much like a Catch 22.

Comment: I can't see in your question neither about dimming workbook as object wouldn't work nor about dimming Excel as object would return a workbook .If you haven't tried my _entire_ code, please do and get back with results. If you already tried my _entire_ code, then please confirm it and state what line throws an error and the error message.

Comment: My aim is to give a solution: to do this I need to know the answers to my questions about running my very code. Once I have them I can possibly develope a solution

Comment: This does not work. I get "438 - Object doesn't support this property or method". I think it is referring to myexl.Visible. After a couple of years of sporadic attempts I have come to the conclusion that VBA on Office for Mac is fundamentally broken...

Answer (score 1):

To open an excel file from word, you do need to define myexl as Object. You also define myworkbook as object.

This solution was taken from "https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/how-do-i-open-a-specific-excel-file-through-vba-in/19201a70-6afe-4799-96bf-521cc6020718". I tested it just now and it worked, let me know if you run into issues.

```
Dim myexl As Object
Dim myworkbook As Object
Dim my_path As String = "C:\Path\WorkbookName.xlsx"

On Error Resume Next
    Set myexl = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
    If Err Then
        Set myexl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
    Set myworkbook = myexl.Workbooks.Open(FileName:=my_path)
    myexl.Visible = True
lbl_Exit:
    Set myexl = Nothing
    Set myworkbook = Nothing
    Exit Sub
End Sub
```